# problem in javascript, running on online platform but not on local browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on the project: **chrome-extension**. I have load the files as extension and they are working fine. But when I am running the index.html on my localbrowser it's actually not working and doing nothing. I think there's some problem with my index.js
can someone let me know where is the issue?

**index.js**:-

```
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let myLeads = []
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"))
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector("#delete-btn")
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")
        
if(leadsFromLocalStorage){
  myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
  render(myLeads)
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    localStorage.clear()
    myLeads=[]
    render(myLeads)
})

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads",JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)

})

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    myLeads.push(tabs[0].url) 
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads) 
    })

})

function render(leads){
    let listItems = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < leads.length ; i++){
    listItems += `<li>
<a target="_blank" href="${leads[i]}">
  ${leads[i]} 
  </a> 
 </li> 
`
    }    
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}
```

**index.html** :-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LiveTracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input-el">
    <button type="button" id="input-btn" >SAVE INPUT</button>
    <button type="button" id="tab-btn" >SAVE TAB</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete-btn" >DELETE ALL</button>
    
    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <h7>Created by Shubharthak </h7>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: How are you initializing `localStorage.getItem("myLeads")`?  I would imagine it's null

Comment: I see, basically there is no local storage in local web browser, it that's the reason it not able to get any item from localStorage?

Comment: Local Storage is literally built into the browser, but there's nothing in your question that shows how the item called "myLeads" is being added to localStorage

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running the index.html on my localbrowser"? If you open this index.html as a http/https/file page then it's not an extension page so it doesn't have access to any extension data or API.

Comment: Basically I want it to execute my SAVE INPUT button, When I was not using localStorage or doesn't created any .json file, it was working fine but now it's not running any button. But I think it's because of the fact that localStorage saves under browser but not on localbrowser I guess maybe thats why it's not executing any button